# Dynamic SQL output

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

How to output results of dynamic SQL for each row returned by a cursor?

This is my statement. I want to compare tables using dynamic SQL and dblinks.

```
DECLARE
    CURSOR c1 IS
        select dbname, dblink from monitor.dblink;

    v_dbname VARCHAR2(30);
    v_dblink VARCHAR2(30);
    v_sql    VARCHAR2(200);
    v_value  VARCHAR2(30);

BEGIN
    OPEN c1;
    LOOP
        FETCH c1 INTO v_dbname,v_dblink;
        EXIT WHEN c1%NOTFOUND;   

        BEGIN   
            v_sql:= 'select concat(owner,table_name) from monitor.exp_tab_mon where dbname='||q'('v_dbname')'||' minus select concat(owner,table_name) from dba_tables@'||v_dblink;
            execute immediate v_sql into v_value;
        EXCEPTION
            when no_data_found then
                dbms_output.put_line('RETURN' || v_value);
        END;

        dbms_output.put_line('RETURN' || v_value);
    END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Output is:

```
SQL> /

RETURN
RETURN
RETURN
RETURN
RETURN
RETURN
RETURN
RETURN
RETURN
RETURN
RETURN
RETURN
RETURN
RETURN
RETURN
```

How can I change this so that when "no data found" output is 0, else output the data.

Comment: You can put a `dbms_output.put_line(v_sql);` to see your sql after v_sql statement.

Answer (score 1):

You could hide the no_data_found exception, and display needed output simply by v_value:

```
BEGIN
OPEN c1;
LOOP
    FETCH c1 INTO v_dbname,v_dblink;
    EXIT WHEN c1%NOTFOUND;   
    v_sql:= 'select concat(owner,table_name) from monitor.exp_tab_mon where dbname='||q'('v_dbname')'||' minus select concat(owner,table_name) from dba_tables@'||v_dblink;
    BEGIN
       EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql into v_value;
       EXCEPTION
          WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
          NULL;
       END;
    END;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('RETURN ' || NVL(v_value, '0');
END LOOP;
```

Comment: hi,how to change  create or replace procedure statement?

Answer (score 0):

@Lay Chris I using SQL Developer, to the left side of Developer i have connection pane. In Drop Down menu have Procedures, click on them, You got a list of all procedures. Double click on one of them, will open new tab with statement of procedures. Just u change it, and after that Click on Compile for debug, and so if it is ok, after leaving Developer save changes. I am doing on that way

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are getting two lines of output every time you have a no data found.  Try with the `continue;` I've added in your exception block so that it puts the output you want in the exception scenario then continues the loop.

```
    DECLARE
        CURSOR c1 IS
            select dbname, dblink from monitor.dblink;

        v_dbname VARCHAR2(30);
        v_dblink VARCHAR2(30);
        v_sql    VARCHAR2(200);
        v_value  VARCHAR2(30);

    BEGIN
        OPEN c1;
        LOOP
            FETCH c1 INTO v_dbname,v_dblink;
            EXIT WHEN c1%NOTFOUND;   

            BEGIN   
                v_sql:= 'select concat(owner,table_name) from monitor.exp_tab_mon where dbname='||q'('v_dbname')'||' minus select concat(owner,table_name) from dba_tables@'||v_dblink;
                execute immediate v_sql into v_value;
            EXCEPTION
                when no_data_found then
                    dbms_output.put_line('0' || v_value);
                    continue;
            END;

            dbms_output.put_line('RETURN' || v_value);
        END LOOP;
    END;
    /
```

Comment: ok,thanks man, if i wanna make a "create or replace procedure" ,and exec，how to do that?